# Permission denied as root

Tags: debian, permissions, repository, software-updates

new clean Debian 10 install. Software manager does not work. Have to add where to look for updates. update does not work because the wrong repository was entered during installation. Right-click does not give me an open option on the source. list I am logged is as root.

```
root@dreams:/# /etc/apt/sources.list
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
```

Comment: did you mean `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to *execute* `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Because it is not a valid executable (it's just a regular ASCII text file) and does not have the execute permission, this won't work.

You'll need to use a text editor to modify `sources.list`, e.g. `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: or `apt edit-sources`

Comment: nano /etc/apt/sources.list   Worked !

Comment: @user372892 happy to hear that it worked! Please click the checkmark on this Answer so that the system knows that your problem has been solved. Thank you!